# determining viability of routes generated with polymorphic_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got a generic partial that includes a link if the object is linkable.

The URL is generated with polymorphic_url.  If polymorphic_url raises NoMethodError, then I don't include the link.

This mostly works great, except where a resource has an update or destroy action but not a show action.  In that case polymorphic_url generates a valid URL, it's just not valid with GET.

Is there any way to restrict polymorphic_url to a specific request method, or a nice way to determine if the returned URL is valid for GET?

Comment: It's definitely an annoying problem.   Rails obviously knows how to route a URL & request_method to a controller method, I just haven't found a way to get it do that for me rather than for rack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a second look at recognize_path, and got it to work.

```
  begin
    url = polymorphic_url(...)
    # validate URL, since polymorphic URL may return a URL for a
    # different method
    Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(url, {:method => 'GET')
    url
  rescue NoMethodError => e  # raised if polymorphic_url fails
    nil
  rescue ActionController::RoutingError => e  # raised if recognize_path fails
    nil
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on your setting, but can't you find a path to the controller in question and thus find out, whether he knows the show action?

Comment: This is for a plugin, so I don't want to make too many assumptions.  Your solution assumes that there's a 1:1 mapping between models and controllers, and that the GET action is mapped to the show method.  Safe assumptions for most standard rails apps, but will break if people actually try to make a real MVC app rather than a standard rails MV app.